# How to delete in Oracle SQL from 2 tables where foreign key constraint by JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, sql-delete

Basically, I need to know the SQL query to perform the JDBC coding. I made my table with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE MASTER 
(
    ROOM_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MARKET VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)  NOT NULL,
    MODIFIED_DATE DATE,
    MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(60 CHAR)
);

CREATE TABLE FEATURES
(
    MASTER_ROOM_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ELEMENT NUMBER NOT NULL,
    MODIFIED_DATE DATE,
    MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(60 CHAR),

    CONSTRAINT FK_MASTER_FEATURES 
        FOREIGN KEY (MASTER_ROOM_ID) REFERENCES MASTER (ROOM_ID)  
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then tried to delete as :

```
DELETE MASTER FEATURES 
JOIN FEATURES ON room_id = master_room_id 
WHERE room_id = master_room_id;
```

It is not a valid query. How to do it?

**Updated question**: it is on delete cascade. When I delete as `delete from master where market = 'xxx';` It only deletes master table rows. Not from the feature. Someone commented that I have to delete from the Features table first. But the problem is that I can't really delete from feature table first. I want to delete by the market. I for the feature table I know only the MASTER_ROOM_ID which is the foreign key for the feature table. So how can I write a query to delete from the feature table first? Please tell me how?

Comment: You cannot do that.  If you have cascading deletes, then you just need to delete from MASTER table.  The FK constraint tells oracle what rows to delete from the child table.

Comment: The problem is that when I deleted row from master as where market = 'xxx'. All row from master is deleted, but not all the row in features not  deleted. So I'm trying to delete by some other conditions

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include example data which demonstrates the problems you're seeing. Thanks.

Comment: Let's say I don't have ON DELETE CASCADE. How do I delete by sql query from 2 tables

Comment: There is no way, to DELETE from 2 tables without ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: You need to first delete from FEATURES, then from MASTER

Comment: Please check the updated question and let me know how can I delete from the FEATURES table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the FK was really created with ON DELETE CASCADE, then deleting from MASTER **will** delete from the features table [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08c2b561f5acaa6b2889fafb0fc9332d)

If the FK was not created with ON DELETE CASCADE, then the delete on the master will fail as long as there is at least one feature referencing it [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90a907f01eed87a64f0a0b2b244b4ef0)

In that case you need to delete from `features` first using a sub-query to find the right rows:

```
delete from features
where master_room_id in (select room_id
                         from master
                         where marked = 'm1');
```

Then you can delete from the master table:

```
delete from master
where marked = 'm1';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=224fece316b2ee8a31a827a0d756ca26)

Comment: I created master table exactly as your demo with the ON DELETE CASCADE. But it only deletes from master nothing from features. So how to verify that ON DELETE CASCADE is applied properly for the feature table.